# Selenium AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently scraping a webpage trying to get a list of locations for a job. The problem is that I need to put it into a list and make it printable but it tells me the title AttributeError.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
PATH = "D:\CDriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
LIST = []

driver.get('https://jobs.gecareers.com/global/en/job/R3570239/Service-Project-Leader-Digital-Solutions')
time.sleep(2)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[au-target-id="127"]')
for ele in elements:
    LIST.append(ele)

print(LIST.text)
driver.quit()
```

If you want to see the website im scraping it is in the driver.get().

Comment: Maybe you want to add `ele.text` to your list instead? I.e. `LIST.append(ele.text)`

Answer (score 0):

**Selenium** `.text` is meant for `web element`  not for `list`. hence you are getting the above exception.

try to do this instead :

```
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.text)
    LIST.append(ele)
```